# VB.Net Interface Visual Studio 2008 font color settings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, resharper

Is it possible to change the color of the font that Interface Names appear in using VB.Net and Resharper/VS2008?

I have been successful changing the interface Names in C# but no luck with VB :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.  You can change the color of the Interface keyword but you must change the color of all Keywords to be this color.  There is no way in VB to only change the name of the Interface keyword.  This is an unfortunate limitation in VS 2008.